# How do I increment a string value in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Long time Lurker reporting in! My issue is I'm not sure how to increment an Item no. It follows this format : LK0001 the row below it will be LK0002, below that LK0003 and so on I'm not sure how to automate this process, as you can tell I'm fairly new to google spreadsheets Sorry if it's already answered , I just can't seem to find it! Thanks!

Weej

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest using the following ID build-up:

> LK1000

This way characters (`LK`) can be separated from integers (`1000`). Otherwise you would face the problem, that if you increase `LK0009` by `1` it becomes `LK00010` and not `LK0010`

ID's need to be "hard coded", meaning `=CONCAT` or `=A1+1` or `=MAX(A:A)+1` are not allowed.

Either go by typing LK+max. number and use the ID as a text or go for the integers and use `CONCAT` when needed.

If you chose to go with the integers, you can easily increment them by doing this:
[image]

and then dragging it downwards, yielding:
[image]

I've prepared an example for you: [How do I increment a string value in Google Spreadsheet?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdHR3MzVrcXdrOEVQQURGUXRiSzBiUUE)

Comment: OH my lord! This is an amazingly detailed answer! Indeed, I did run into the exact numbering issues you mentioned, I shoudl have started with the LK1000 as you suggested, still , all in all amazing answer, thanks!